# making ul styled buttons the same same size

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make the buttons stretched out to make a uniform list but I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my sidebar.  The following code makes the buttons appear but makes them only as big as the word on it.  I would like for them to be uniform in size.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="avmenu"><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="care.php">Care</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="table.php">Table</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="othervideos.php">Other Videos</a></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul#avmenu{
    margin:35px 0;
    padding:0;
    font:12px Verdana;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul#avmenu li a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#avmenu a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#222;
}
ul#avmenu li.current a {
    border:1px solid #777;
}
```

Comment: Is `<li>&nbsp;</li>` supposed to be some sort of spacer? You really should use margins for that instead.

Comment: @animuson I added a margin fix in my answer that should work for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `display:block` to your `<a>` tag. Write like this:

```
ul#avmenu li a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
display:block;
width:<width>px;
```

to `ul#avmenu li a`

**EDIT:**
You can also remove the extra `<li>&nbsp;</li>` by adding:

```
ul#avmenu li{
    margin:12px 0;
}
```

And you have a duplication of `list-style:none` in your css by the way.

Note: I prefer using `min-width:;` rather than plain width as it allows the items to still look right in case of overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#avmenu{
    margin:35px 0;
    padding:0;
    font:12px Verdana;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#avmenu li a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#avmenu a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#222;
}
#avmenu li.current a {
    border:1px solid #777;
}
</style>
<ul id="avmenu"><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="care.php">Care</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="table.php">Table</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="othervideos.php">Other Videos</a></li>
<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your code is fine , you just need to remove ul from every class name.

Comment: removing `ul` from `ul#avmenu` makes no difference; I think you are presumeing it is `ul #avmenu` which implies a child of `ul` with id `avmenu`

Answer (score 1):

1. add one  tag in 
   e.g  `<li>&nbsp;</li><li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>`
2. add this css

   *#avmenu li a span {
   width :100px !important;
   display:inline-block;
   }*

done cheers